# Merge 3 arrays into a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have three separate arrays that I would like to merge into a multidimensional array

```
    Array 3 [1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1]
    Array 2 [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 6, 1]
    Array 1 [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

The output that I would like to have is where all the arrays are in one multidimensional array where they are all stacked on top of each other.

Finial Array =

```
     Array 3
     Array 2
     Array 1
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: And what have you tried? We help you solve your problems (or homework), we dont do it for you. Always include your own efforts please, instead of just dumping your requirements onto other people.

Comment: What kind of arrays are those? `int[]` or `long[]` or `Integer[]` or `Long[]`? Or anything else?

Comment: Those are Int[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MultiDimensionalArrayDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ROWS = 3;
        final int COLUMNS = 10;

        int array1 [] = {  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9};
        int array2 [] = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};
        int array3 [] = { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};

        int finalArray[][] =  new int[ROWS][];
        finalArray[0] = array1;
        finalArray[1] = array2;
        finalArray[2] = array3;

        System.out.println("Initial bi-dimensional array:");
        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d ",finalArray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<ROWS-1; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++) {
                if(finalArray[i][j]==0) {
                    moveColumnUp(IntStream.range(i, ROWS).mapToObj(obj -> finalArray[obj]).toArray(int[][]::new),ROWS-i,j);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("After transformation:");
        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<COLUMNS; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%2d ",finalArray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void moveColumnUp(int matrix [][], int numberOfRows, int columnIndex) {
        int firstRowElement = matrix[0][columnIndex]; // temporarily store first row so it can be placed last
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfRows-1; i++) {
            matrix[i][columnIndex] = matrix[i+1][columnIndex];
        }
        matrix[numberOfRows-1][columnIndex] = firstRowElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Also it possible to remove zeros on the top and second layer by moving the numbers up. For eg. on colum1  0,10,20 becomes 10,20,0 ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand if that was a question.

Comment: yeah it was a question

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for, please "accept answer". This way the rest of the people here looking to help someone know that this question is already taken care of.

Comment: I believe that what you're trying to do in that comment is just saying:
  finalArray[0] = array2;
  finalArray[1] = array3;
  finalArray[2] = array1;
Instead of:
  finalArray[0] = array1;
  finalArray[1] = array2;
  finalArray[2] = array3;

Comment: "finalArray" is your multidimensional (in this case, bi-dimensional) array. Look at its content as finalArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]. If you want to move everything up, you just need to do a for loop that will do so. I will edit my answer to show you that.

Comment: Done, any more questions?

Comment: Thanks but what i wanted was if there was a zero in top or middle row. It would only move that individual column up. So the zero would be at the bottom. My bad in the initial explanation

Comment: Ok so that's quite a lot more complex. I edited the answer. I think it works as you wanted.